# Integro-Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convolution, integro-differential-equations

I was attempting to solve the following integro-differential equation using convolutions. My answer also had a convolution which did not seem right and was wondering if someone would check my process.

[Problem with initial work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P15X.jpg)

[My final solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoMfv.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y'(t)=1-\int_0^t y(t-\tau ) \exp (-2 \tau ) \, d\tau$$
Laplace Transform:
$$s \left(\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)\right)-y(0)=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)}{2+s}$$

We have $y(0)=1$ and solve for $\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)$:

$$\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)=\frac{2+s}{s (1+s)}$$
$$\mathcal{L}_t[y(t)](s)=\frac{2}{s}-\frac{1}{1+s}$$

Inverse Laplace Transform:

$$y(t)=2-e^{-t}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I messed up on the "tails" for the initial data because I forgot it was only the first derivative.